# Cucumber/Maven: How to make variable in pom.xml for use Cucumber options?

Tags: maven, cucumber, pom.xml

I need get feature scenarios without running tests with maven via cmd. Cucumber has '*dryRun*' option. But don`t know how to add this option to *pom.xml*. I tried many variants, but it not helped.

Type in cmd:

```
mvn verify -Dfeature=Forum.feature -DdryRun=false
```

but I got error. -DdryRun options does not works.

Please take a look screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td4Of.jpg

Comment: Please embed the relevant parts of the pom.xml in your post, as that makes it easier to quote and point to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot you have the following configuration:

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
    <cucumber.options>
        <![CDATA[--tags ${tags} ${dryRun} [${cucumber.features.dir}/${feature}]]>
    </cucumber.options>
</systemPropertyVariables>
```

This would insert `true` or `false` into the environment variable, which is not a valid option and instead gets interpreted as a path to a feature file.

Cucumber instead expects a parameter like `--dry-run` or `--no-dry-run` (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/v1.2.0/core/src/main/java/cucumber/runtime/RuntimeOptions.java#L116). The solution would be to define your property like this:

```
<properties>
    <dryRun>--dry-run</dryRun>
</properties>
```

Unrelated to that, the opening brace before the feature path would also cause cucumber not to find the feature.

Comment: @user2837153 thanks, if this answer solved your question you can mark it as accepted. There should be some kind of check mark on the left near the voting arrows.