# In a project, is there any way to check if all the steps have matching step definitions

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, gherkin

I'm working on a selenium framework in IntelliJ. Please let me know if there is any way to know if any step is not having its corresponding step definition. Its tedious to get into each and every feature file and see whether all the steps have step definitions.

**Use case :** If I delete any step definition, then I should know the feature files affected due to that, without navigating to each and every feature file

Answer (score 1):

Use dryRun option, instructions in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562331/cucumber-maven-how-to-make-variable-in-pom-xml-for-use-cucumber-options)

Answer (score 0):

Download Cucumber Plugin for IntelliJ and it should help

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-from-feature-file-to-step-definition.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Cucumber plugin. As I've mentioned my use case in the question, can you help in that way? I've around 30 feature files and 7 step definition files(JAVA). Now, If I delete any step definition, then I should know the feature files affected due to that, without navigating to each and every feature file.

Answer (score 0):

Also an option - RubyMine is a great IDE from the same company as IntelliJ and natively supports Gherkin/Cucumber. It marks steps that don't have matching step definitions and can auto-generate the stub for you as well. Additionally, it supports converting Scenarios to Scenario Outlines and has a feature to check your step definition Regex against a string right in the editor.

Just a few of the things I noticed when switching from Komodo the other day. Very happy with the choice. If you are developing with a company and licensing may be an issue, you may get lucky and already have the subscription that allows for using any of JetBrain's IDEs.

Comment: As you mentioned, it marks steps that don't have matching definitions. But, its not feasible for me to jump into all the feature files and see whether any steps are affected when I delete a Step definition. Can you pls help. Thanks for the info on licensing